# Summarise R stars objects by group

Tags: r, stars

I would like to summarise the bands of a stars object using a band as a grouping variable.

In this small example, I have two bands with information on e.g. species densities. In addition, I have a group variable (3rd band).

```
library(stars)
library(tidyverse)
library(ids)

set.seed(20)

toy_data <- reduce(rerun(2, {
  m <- matrix(sample(seq(0, 100, 1), 20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
  dim(m) <- c(x = 5, y = 4)
  st_as_stars(m) %>% setNames(ids::adjective_animal(1))
}), c)

group <- matrix(sample(1:4, 20, replace = TRUE), nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
dim(group) <- c(x = 5, y = 4)
group <- st_as_stars(group) %>% setNames("group")

dataR <- merge(c(toy_data, group))
```

Next, I would like to get median values for each species (band 1,2) and for each group (band 3). I could transfer the stars object into tibble and to the stats:

```
dataR %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("x", "y"), names_from = "attributes", values_from = X) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% select(-x, -y) %>% summarise_all(list(~ median(., na.rm = T)))
```

However, if it is a very large spatial stars object that seems like a band option and I am sure that it could be done in a more efficient and direct way.

Comment: I don't see a way of doing summaries within stars BUT If efficiency is your concern then use data.table instead of tibbles anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the data is in a native R array in `dataR$X`, the most direct approach would be to work with that rather than add several layers of add-on packages and unneccessary data structure manipulation.

Using `tapply`, here's median on the first two layers:

```
> tapply(dataR$X[,,"inflatable_partridge"],dataR$X[,,3], median)
   1    2    3    4 
47.0 61.0 61.5 44.0 
> tapply(dataR$X[,,"arbitrary_stork"],dataR$X[,,3], median)
   1    2    3    4 
40.5 35.5 42.5 28.5
```

write a loop or another "apply" family function for N layers, and rearrange into a table structure as desired.

I don't know if for large data stars doesn't store the data in an element and instead accesses via a proxy object to avoid large objects in memory, if so you'll need to either load it in anyway or work at a lower level to load the data in by chunks.

Comment: That makes sense and seems to be the fastest way too. Thanks!